# scan folder for virus using php and clamav?

Tags: php

I am using cPanel on my server. It is a Linux shared server.

I have the clamAv antivirus installed on the cpanel and I can scan the server by going to Virus Scanner tab from the cpanel.

But what i need to do is to use the clamav in a php file.

I tried using the following code in the PHP file but I get nothing (neither OK message or any other messages) on the php page when I run the page from the browser.

Could someone please let me know if I'm missing something?

```
<?php

$output = 'myFolder';

$result = 'myFolder';

exec("clamscan '$filename'", $output, $result);

if ($result === 0) {
     echo 'everything ok :)';
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably don't have the permission to launch executables, as this is a shared server.

Comment: If there's a specific reason you need this, you should let us know so we can assist you better.

Comment: @pyerwin, any suggestions on what I can use instead? because i am allowing users to upload files onto my server and i will need to scan them before allowing the files to be placed in the server.

Comment: @esqew, Thanks. I have provided the reason for doing this in my message above.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [`php-clamav`](http://php-clamav.sourceforge.net/) which provides native PHP functions for interacting with ClamAV, specifically the [`cl_scanfile(string $filename, string $virusname)`](http://php-clamav.sourceforge.net/#clscanfile) call.

From the sample code:

```
$retcode = cl_scanfile($file, $virusname);
if ($retcode == CL_VIRUS) {
    echo "File path : ".$file."Return code : ".cl_pretcode($retcode)."Virus found name : ".$virusname; 
} else {
    echo "File path : ".$file."Return code : ".cl_pretcode($retcode); 
}
```

Do note, however, that ClamAV must be installed on the host machine in order for `php-clamav` to function properly.

Comment: I did look at php-clamav before posting this question! I even tried this code  $ret = cl_info(); echo $ret; to see the version of the clamav version in my php page but I get nothing in my php page. only a white page! so i don't know what's missing!

Comment: the clamav is installed in the cpanel because as i said in my question, i can go to Virus Scanner tab from the cpanel and it says that clamAv is installed and i can run the clamav from there too.

Comment: @user3759758 Just because you can use ClamAV from the control panel doesn't mean it's accessible from PHP. The only people who can give you details on that would be your webhost. Get in touch with them.